# Problem with drop off when sculpting rock face

Tags: sculpting, append, brushes

I'm trying to sculpt rock faces in blender. My normal work flow was to append photos sscanned rock textures to my draw brush in sculpt mode and then go from there. Since downloading the newest blender when using this brush they are creating a big bulge every time I 'drag' them out. (see photo) I assume it's something to do with drop off, however if I change the drop off to make it less bulbous the rock texture is hardly seen and this wasn't happening previously. Any ideas?
Thanks[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem! After clicking almost every option in the brushes settings, clicking the Vector Displacement checkbox under the Texture Tab is what did it for me!
[image: Location of Vector Displacement checkbox]